# Cannot find custom plugins in maven local repo

Tags: kotlin, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've made a custom plugin and uploaded it to local maven

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    id("com.vanniktech.maven.publish") version "0.27.0"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

val pluginId = "${group}.${rootProject.name}"
println(pluginId)

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register(rootProject.name) {
            id = pluginId
            displayName = "Kotlin Userscript"
            description = "Allows creating browser userscripts in Kotlin/JS."
            implementationClass = "org.example.KotlinUserscriptPlugin"
        }
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

After `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

I've tried to use it in another project.

`settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

//buildscript {
//    dependencies {
//        classpath("org.example:user-script:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
//    }
//}

plugins {
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version "0.5.0"
}

//apply(plugin = "org.example.user-script")



rootProject.name = "uScript"
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.21"
    id("org.example.user-script") version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

but I get:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Cyber\IdeaProjects\uScript\build.gradle.kts' line: 1

Plugin [id: 'org.example.user-script', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.example.user-script', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.example.user-script:org.example.user-script.gradle.plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/C:/Users/Cyber/.m2/repository/)
```

however, I can add it as a *dependency* library but not as a **plugin**.

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.21"
//    id("org.example.user-script") version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("org.example:user-script:1.0-SNAPSHOT")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```

But it is a plugin not library. How do I use this in another project as a plugin?

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but try to use `id("user-script")`. Currently, gradle tries to find this artifact `'org.example.user-script:org.example.user-script.gradle.plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT'` which clearly doesn't exist. [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers) might help.